# iOS different kind of object initialisation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I was trying to integrate [RESideMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu) to my application. I was trying to understand how it works to be able to customize a little bit more. Than, i've encountered this initialisation that i've never seen before. I couldn't seem to find any official docs or any questions on SO which explains it a little bit more. If it does, please point me in the right direction.

Here is the code i'm talking about

```
self.tableView = ({
        UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (self.view.frame.size.height - 54 * 5) / 2.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 54 * 5) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView.dataSource = self;
        tableView.opaque = NO;
        tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tableView.backgroundView = nil;
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        tableView.bounces = NO;
        tableView.scrollsToTop = NO;
        tableView;
    });
```

So, Is it a new language feature that allows us to initialise objects a different way. It's kind of like `Object Initializer in C#`.

It would be any difference, if i had initialized like following

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (self.view.frame.size.height - 54 * 5) / 2.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 54 * 5) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.tableView setDelegate:self];
[self.tableView setDataSource:self];
[self.tableView setOpaque:NO];
....
...
```

Last question, does this kind of initialisation apply to any `UIKit` class or any `Foundation` class ?

**EDIT**
If i comment this last line of code in the initialisation which is `tableView;` It gives me compile error which is  **Implicit conversion of 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to 'UITableView *' is disallowed with ARC**, why is this happening ? The last line is kind of return statement or what ?

Thanks.

Comment: In response to your edit: I'm assuming that the entire block evaluates to whatever the last line evaluates to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just FTR, there is **no difference** if you use the conventional code.

(Much like with json, say, you can now very simply say dict[@"someKey"] directly - but there's no fundamental difference.)

Thanks for pointing this out !!

Comment: Very cool. Were you able to find this feature documented anywhere?

Comment: do you know is it a new feature or it's always been there ? Does it apply to any kind of object initialization ?